# PyQt connect SIGNAL to multiple SLOT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to learn `PyQt` from `rapid gui programming with python and qt` and currently learning `Signals` and `Slots`.

Below is a short snippet of my code:

```
self.connect(self.dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.spinbox.setValue) #1
self.connect(self.dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.getValue_dial)    #2
self.connect(self.spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.dial.setValue)
self.connect(self.spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.getValue_spinbox)

def getValue_dial(self):
        print self.dial.value()

def getValue_spinbox(self):
        print self.dial.value()
```

What I am trying to achieve here is call `2` SLOTS at once that is `spinbox.setValue` and `getValue_dial` for `dial` object as soon as `ValueChanged(int)` signal is emitted.

The above code executes successfully without any errors and `print` the appropriate values as they are changed.

Now my question is the above way appropriate to call multiple slots for a single signal.?

Can the above two statements(1 & 2) be combined into a single statement.

Here is the link for my [complete code](http://pastie.org/3930507).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way you're doing it is fine. If you had quite a few things to do you could connect to a new function that handles everything for you.

I notice in your connected `getValue` functions you're getting the value straight from the object; are you aware that the value is passed as a parameter with the `valueChanged(int)` signal? If you change your `getValue` functions to accept an additional parameter there will be no need to get the value directly from the object. Of course you could do away with the `getValue` function all together and issue your print statement in the helper function.

```
self.connect(self.dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), self.dial_value_changed)
self.connect(self.spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.spinbox_value_changed)

def dial_value_changed(self, value):
    self.spinbox.setValue(value)
    self.getValue_dial(value)

def spinbox_value_changed(self, value):
    self.dial.setValue(value)
    self.getValue_spinbox(value)

def getValue_dial(self, value):
        print value

def getValue_spinbox(self, value):
        print value
```

Also, and this is down to preference, there is a [new style for signals and slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) which can make the code a little easier to read. It would change the

```
self.connect(self.dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), self.dial_value_changed)
self.connect(self.spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"),self.spinbox_value_changed)
```

lines above to

```
self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_value_changed)
self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_value_changed)
```

But for the original question and for the two things you're doing I'd just connect the signal twice rather than have a helper function.

Comment: ok I understand when dial value is changed this signal is emitted with new value as an argument but how are we able to access that value directly as a variable `value`. I mean don't we require some `dial` object specific calls.How come are we able to access it just by the variable name `value`.

Comment: QDial inherits from QAbstractSlider. In the [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) you can see that `valueChanged` passes an int when emitted and that the int is the value of the slider.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list to connect the two slots/functions in a single statement:

```
# in Python 2.X
map(self.dial.valueChanged.connect, [self.spinbox.setValue, self.getValue_dial])

# in Python 3.X (map returns an iterator instead of processing the list)
list(map(self.dial.valueChanged.connect, [self.spinbox.setValue, self.getValue_dial]))

# or with any Python version
[self.dial.valueChanged.connect(x) for x in [self.spinbox.setValue, self.getValue_dial]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the appropriate way, yes. You `can't combine` the two CONNECT statements into one.